# Sorting strings in custom lexicographic order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Sorting string array according to lexicographic order with a custom ordering (a permutation of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`). This is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author sabertooth
 */
public class SortString {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static char[] index;
    private static BufferedReader br;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int testCases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            String dictionary = br.readLine();

            index = new char[dictionary.length()];
            index = dictionary.toCharArray();

            int set = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            String[] unsortedInput = new String[set];
            String[] sortedInput = new String[set];
            for (int j = 0; j < set; j++) {
                unsortedInput[j] = br.readLine();
            }

            if (unsortedInput.length <= 1) {
                System.out.println(unsortedInput[0]);
            } else {
                // merge sort on this array
                sortedInput = mergeSort(unsortedInput);
                for (int k = 0; k < sortedInput.length; k++) {
                    System.out.println(sortedInput[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String[] mergeSort(String[] unsortedInput) {
        if (unsortedInput.length <= 1) {
            return unsortedInput;
        }

        String[] left;
        String[] right;
        int middle = unsortedInput.length / 2;
        if (unsortedInput.length % 2 == 0) {
            left = new String[middle];
            right = new String[middle];
        } else {
            left = new String[middle];
            right = new String[middle + 1];
        }
        System.arraycopy(unsortedInput, 0, left, 0, middle);
        System.arraycopy(unsortedInput, middle, right, 0, unsortedInput.length - middle);

        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);
        return merge(left, right);
    }

    private static String[] merge(String[] left, String[] right){
        List<String> leftList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> rightList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        leftList.addAll(Arrays.asList(left));
        rightList.addAll(Arrays.asList(right));

        while (leftList.size() > 0 || rightList.size() > 0) {
             if (leftList.size() > 0 && rightList.size() > 0) {
                // my own comparison
                if (compare(leftList.get(0), rightList.get(0)) == -1) {
                    // leftString is less than right string
                    result.add(leftList.get(0));
                    leftList = leftList.subList(1, leftList.size());
                } else
                if (compare(leftList.get(0), rightList.get(0)) == 1) {
                    //left string is greater than right string
                    result.add(rightList.get(0));
                    rightList = rightList.subList(1, rightList.size());
                } else
                if (compare(leftList.get(0), rightList.get(0)) == 0) {
                    // leftString is equal to right string
                    result.add(leftList.get(0));
                    leftList = leftList.subList(1, leftList.size());
                }
            } else
            if (leftList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < leftList.size(); i++) {
                    result.add(leftList.get(i));
                }
                leftList.clear();
            } else
            if (rightList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < rightList.size(); i++) {
                    result.add(rightList.get(i));
                }
                rightList.clear();
            }
        }
        String[] sortedInput = new String[result.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            sortedInput[i] = result.get(i);
        }
        return sortedInput;
    }

    private static int compare(String leftString, String rightString) {
        // return -1 if left string is less than right string else left string is greater than right string return 1

        int min = Math.min(leftString.length(), rightString.length());
        int response = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            if (compareChar(leftString.charAt(i), rightString.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                response = -1;
                break;
            } else
            if (compareChar(leftString.charAt(i), rightString.charAt(i)) == 1) {
                response = 1;
                break;
            } else
            if (compareChar(leftString.charAt(i), rightString.charAt(i)) == 0) {
                response = 0;

            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    private static int compareChar(char x, char y) {
        // returns true if x < y
        int indexofx = 0;
        int indexofy = 0;
        int response = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
            if (index[i] == x) {
                indexofx = i;
            }
            if (index[i] == y) {
                indexofy = i;
            }
        }
        if (indexofx < indexofy) {
            response = -1;
        } else
        if (indexofx > indexofy) {
            response = 1;
        } else
        if (indexofx == indexofy) {
            response = 0;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run this for some of the inputs the output is correct and for other the output is not correct. I have been debugging it but not able to find the bug.

**EDITS**:

> Adriana was playing with the English alphabet. When she was done playing with the alphabet, she realised that she had jumbled up the positions of the letters. Now, given a set of words, she wondered what would be the dictionary ordering of these words based on the new alphabet ordering which she made.
>
> In other words, given a permutation of the English alphabet, E and a set of words S, you need to output the lexicographical ordering of the words in the set S based on the new alphabet, E.
>
> Input:
>
> The first line will contain a single integer, T, denoting the number of test cases. T lines follow.
>
> For each test case:
>
> The first line will contain a string, E, the new alphabet ordering, which will be a permutation of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
>
> The next line will contain a single integer M, the size of the set S. S lines follow, each containing a single word, containing lowercase latin characters.
>
> Output: for each test case, output S lines, each line containing one word from the set S, ordered lexicographically.
>
> Constraints
>
> ```
> 1 <= T <= 1000 
> 1 <= M <= 100 
> 1 <= |W| <= 50
> ```
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> 2
> aa
> bb
> bacdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> 2
> aa
> bb
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> aa
> bb
> bb
> aa
> ```

Comment: could give an example when it's not working well

Comment: It is hard to guess (and decipher from the program code) what you are trying to do.  If you can provide what you are trying to achieve, what inputs were correctly sorted (if that's what you meant by 'correct output') and what inputs are not correctly output?

Comment: @Horizon see the edits

Comment: Please show some sample input and right/wrong output

Comment: @AbhishekBansal check edits

Comment: @user3172529 I meant your input/output test cases for which your code fails.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I tried every possible case on my machine and for no case it fails but when I upload it to submission then it fails and for that I don't have test cases apparently there is some bug in this.

Comment: Variant of alien alphabet?

Comment: Hint: there is no need write your own merge-sort code.  Unless your teacher *specifically told you not to*, you should use one of Java SE's built-in `sort` methods and implement the special ordering semantics via a custom `Comparator`.   The more code that you write, the more you need to test / write test cases for, and the more opportunities you have for introducing bugs.   (In the *real world*, coders who gratuitously reimplement standard functionality are just making work for themselves and their co-workers.  A better strategy is to read / search the Java SE javadocs *first*.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any given permutation. Why use custom sort function (unless you have to sort custom class objects) when java provide you inbuilt one?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TestClass {
    public static ArrayList<String> res;
    static void sort(String dictionary, String[] words, int count){
        String eng = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String[] tempArray = new String[count];
        String temp="";
        char ch;
        int index, m=0;
        for(String x : words){
            temp = "";
            for(int l =0 ;l<x.length(); l++){
                ch = x.charAt(l);
                index = dictionary.indexOf(ch);
                temp = temp + eng.charAt(index);
            }
            tempArray[m] = temp;
            m++;
        }

        Arrays.sort(tempArray);
        for(String x : tempArray){
            temp = "";
            for(int l =0 ;l<x.length(); l++){
                ch = x.charAt(l);
                index = eng.indexOf(ch);
                temp = temp + dictionary.charAt(index);
            }
            res.add(temp);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        res = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        int count;
        String [] words;
        String dictionary;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            dictionary = br.readLine();
            count = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            words = new String[count];
            for(int j =0; j<count; j++){
                words[j] = br.readLine();
            }
            sort(dictionary,words,count);
        }
        for(String x : res)
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

I guess this is some sort of algorithmic challenge. is it? :)

Comment: the dictionary String may not be same every time. It may be qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm then I have to sort according to this string i.e 'q' first 'w' second and so on. 
I solved this problem though there was some error in length of strings when both the strings are equal and of different length. For ex string "q" will come before string "qq".

Comment: Yeah, my solution works perfectly for any permutation of the alphabet order. (unless you didn't try running the code provided.) The dictionary string doesn't need to be same all the time. :) he  dictionary for each test case will be passed to sort method.(see the arguments being passed.) The dictionary eng provided is used for substitution.(means if dictionary being passed is qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm then for input say,'q','qq', the programs checks for index of q in dictionary being passed and finds corresponding alphabet in original english alphabet order.)

Comment: Drive-by-comment: Wouldn't it work to just write a custom comparator? O:)

Answer (score 0):

The string comparison function is incorrect: you only compare on the shortest length, returning `0` for `A` and `AB`.  When a string is a prefix of the other, you should compare the lengths.

The character comparison function is unnecessarily complicated and considers all characters outside of `index` to be identical to the first letter in `index`. You should only reorder lowercase letters according to the `index` string.

```
    private static int compare(String leftString, String rightString) {
        // return -1 if left string is less than right string else left string is greater than right string return 1

        int len1 = leftString.length();
        int len2 = rightString.length();
        int min = Math.min(len1, len2);
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            int cmp = compareChar(leftString.charAt(i), rightString.charAt(i));
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
        }
        return len1 == len2 ? 0 : (len1 < len2 ? -1 : 1);
    } 

    /* lexicographical comparison with custom order for lowercase letters */
    private static int compareChar(char x, char y) {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        int indexofx = index.indexOf(x);
        int indexofy = index.indexOf(y);
        if (indexofx >= 0) {
            x = (char)('a' + indexofx);
        }
        if (indexofy >= 0) {
            y = (char)('a' + indexofy);
        }
        // if index is a permutation of the lowercase letters,
        // we can assume x != y 
        return x < y ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: does not compile, missing cast in `x = 'a' + indexofx;` and `y = 'a' + indexofy;`

Comment: `x = (char) ( 'a' + indexofx);`; the result of addition is an `int`, even if the operands are `char`. Please, don't use `0x61` instead of `'a'` - a `char` is already an integer data type (but not an `int`) and `'a'` is much easier to understand

Comment: @user85421: should we not also cast `'a'` as `(int)'a'` in these expressions?

Comment: if none of the operands are type `double`, `float` or `long`, the *promoted type* of the operation will be `int`; and all operands will undergo widening primitive conversion to `int` - no cast is needed from `char` (`byte`, `short`) to `int` - actually even `'a' + 'b'` will be an `int`. (JLS [5.6. Numeric Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6))

Comment: the cast *back* to (char) is needed exactly because of that implicit promotion to `int`